# How to use the `colspan` in the css dispay table properties?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a css table, since i requried to change this for responsive display in future.

I works buggy, i am not able to create the colspan properly. any one help me? in the top instead of getting 90% and 10% percent, which is not setting properly.

again in the bottom i requried a 100% width, but not setting properly.

```css
#table {
    display:table;
    width:100%
}


.row {
    display:table-row;
}

.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid grey;
}

.row1 {
   display: table-caption;
}

.cell1 {
    width:10%
}

.cell2{
    width:70%
}

.cell9{width:90%}
.cell4{width:40%}
.subcell2{width:20%}
.cell10{width:100%}
```

```html
<div id="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell cell1">30%</div>
        <div class="cell cell2">
            
            <div class="row row1">
                <div class="cell cell9"><h2>90%</h2></div>
                 <div class="cell cell1"><h2>10%</h2></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell cell4"><h2>40%</h2></div>
                <div class="cell subcell2"><h2>20%</h2></div>
                <div class="cell subcell2"><h2>20%</h2></div>
                <div class="cell subcell2"><h2>20%</h2></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell cell10"><h2>100%</h2></div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using twitter bootstrap?

Comment: well if you already give width 90% and then 10% then why you want to stretch that 10% div to end? your question is not clear..please describe more..thanx

Comment: I am not getting you. in the 2 row, last column I am trying to keep as 100%.

Comment: @user2024080 you look like this http://jsfiddle.net/tkgcfpdf/

Comment: yes. post me as answer, is it possible to avoid tables under the rows